# How to fix the problem "JSX element type 'MyCmp' does not have any construct or call signatures." problem in react and react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am learning react native, I simply want to switch the `TouchableNativeFeedback` between `TouchableOpacity` according different OS Platform.

here is my switch function:

```
import { TouchableNativeFeedback, TouchableOpacity, Platform } from "react-native"

export const getMyCmp = () => {
  if (Platform.OS === "android" && Platform.Version >= 21) {
    return TouchableNativeFeedback
  } else {
    return TouchableOpacity
  }
}
```

However, when I use it

```
export const Foo = () => {
  const MyCmp = getMyCmp()
  return (
    <MyCmp onPress={()=>{}}>
        ...
    </MyCmp>
  )
}
```

I got the Error at `MyCmp`: JSX element type 'MyCmp' does not have any construct or call signatures.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Try setting the return type of `getMyCmp` to `TouchableNativeFeedback | TouchableOpacity` or `typeof TouchableNativeFeedback | typeof TouchableOpacity`, not sure which one works.

Comment: @cbr no, this doesn't work, it reported: `This expression is not callable.
  No constituent of type 'TouchableNativeFeedback | TouchableOpacity' is callable.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that TypeScript is having a hard time figuring out the type of the intersection of the two different components' types.

As a workaround, you can manually specify the return type to be `React.ComponentType` with the props type being an intersection of the two components' props.

```
import { ComponentType } from "react";
import {
  Platform,
  TouchableNativeFeedback,
  TouchableNativeFeedbackProps,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableOpacityProps
} from "react-native";

const getMyCmp = (): ComponentType<
  TouchableOpacityProps | TouchableNativeFeedbackProps
> => {
  if (Platform.OS === "android") {
    return TouchableNativeFeedback;
  }
  return TouchableOpacity;
};

export const Foo = () => {
  const MyCmp = getMyCmp();
  return (
    <MyCmp onPress={() => {}}>
      <p>foo</p>
    </MyCmp>
  );
};
```